# Magento build reasonable project turnaround time

Tags: magento

As a new project manager joining a team where ecomerce sites are developed using magento, I have very little experience estimating project times.

What would a reasonable turnaround time be for a typical magento site with some customisations be?

Customisations in terms of custom modules and a completely custom theme.

I'm thinking in terms of 1 or 2 developers per project.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm voting to migrate this to http://programmers.stackexchange.com, but I think it's unlikely you'll get an answer even there... there are too many variables involved. You might be best off asking the actual developers you'll be working with

Comment: I understand the level of variables - I am more interested in some experiences from other developers / project managers involved with magento

Comment: Good question that doesn't belong here, its a more a business question than a programming questions.  You're going to get a wide variety of answers, none of which will be accurate to your situation.  Magento's new enough in the ecosystem that agencies are still figuring out the best way to manage magento projects.

Comment: Hi Alan, the reason I decided to ask the question here is for precisely the point you made about the lack if understanding in agencies. I thought it would be great to hear real experiences from real developers working with magento. I understand though that this is s programming forum so apologies to all if the question is totally out of place. I just can't seem to find any info out there on this topic

Comment: @Jon, in the current economic climate people are loath to share that kind of information.  Most first Magento projects are disasters, but as the team gains experience they starting cranking things out at a faster rate.  The ability to execute on Magento project is their competitive advantage, and people don't share that sort of thing these days (especially in the ecommerce world). Best of luck in the new gig though!

Comment: Project Manager: Can someone please build me a piece of string? Developer/Architect: Sure, how long do you want the string? Project Manager: Umm, just a normal piece of string will be fine...

Comment: @Pekka - rather than asking your internal developers who haven't worked with Magento, much better to approach an experienced Magento freelancer/contractor to help out with your first project, otherwise the "first Magento project disaster" as suggested by @AlanStorm is likely...  Anyone know any Magento freelancers? :P

Comment: @Jonathan but his team seems to already developing Magento sites. Which is why I think they should have some rough estimates at least?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not a programming question and i usually downvote such. You might ask this on https://pm.stackexchange.com/ and in fact there seems to be threads about this matter already going on there https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/basis-of-estimate

Scrum has answers for you http://scrummethodology.com/scrum-effort-estimation-and-story-points/ and start estimating your story's and tasks.

i have a strong agile background and my magento experience tells me:

1. completely new theme with dom changes, hard customization and for example 4 extensions with courses for end user in team of 2 developers, slicer, designer and scrum-master will take you from start to launch within 6 weeks.
2. new theme with css styling no or minimal dom changes, pre-made extensions, 1 dev, slicer, designer, scrum master will take you from start to launch with 5 days. User will learn the system within 2 months of usage or sooner if is smart, till then expect to hold the users hand and answer dumb questions or get bad reviews

those results are based on estimates with pro level devs , designers and slicers who have done at least 12 magento setups before and have been involved with zend and magento development over 2 years in conditions where code is version controlled and deployment, migrations and rollbacks are automated.

For your first project if none of you have used Magento before , expect the dev learning curve from start to pro at least 6 months , slicer from start to pro with magento 1 month and you as project manager to understand the magento and all its features :) well 2  months of daily usage or sooner if you are smarter. For designers its easier to get the box element and mock-up list (list of pages he has to design for each client) to place and you can expect him to get the basis within 5 days